# Microsoft Azure functions (nodejs), WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT and maxConcurrentCalls not doing what they say

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

Using consumption plan. I created a service bus nodejs function trigger app.

I do not use sessions. Tested with two topics - partitioning enabled/disabled.

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

module.exports = async function(context, mySbMsg) {
    context.log('message start:', mySbMsg);
    await timeout(60000)
    context.log('message done:', mySbMsg);
};
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 5,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:09:30"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:09:55"
}
```

With `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` = 1

I expect to see 5 requests/minute per VM running.

Sending 100 messages, I expect to see 5 messages/minute.

I do see 1 vm running in the live metrics. However, I am seeing 1 message a minute in the logs.

[image: logs]

Comment: I suspect that "prefetchCount": 1 is probably the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @Teebu, "`prefetchCount`":1 is the culprit.

---

**Example**:

If `prefetchCount` is set to 200, `maxConcurrentCalls` is set to 16 (assume), then 200 messages will be prefetched to a specific instance, but only 16 messages processed at a time.

Prefetched Messages can be gotten by the `MessageSender` whereas the `MaxConcurrency` is only processed by the client code.

---

`MaxConcurrentCalls` - how many messages will a single `MessageReceiver` process at the same time.

`PrefetchCount` - When initiating a call to receive a message, a single `MessageReceiver` can retrieve up to how many messages.

To the same value, setting those two is **`counterproductive`**.

**`PrefetchCount` should be larger than the number of messages processed concurrently**.

---

In a simple:

The maximum number of messages prefetched by the underlying `MessageReceiver` utilized by Azure Functions SDK is determined by the `prefetchCount`.

To ensure that not too many messages are prefetched and locks are lost while waiting for processing, ensure that `prefetchCount` is properly configured with the value defined for `maxConcurrentCalls`.

Comment: Is there a purpose to having prefetch at all? It seems useless in my case where I only want 1 or very few items. Setting it to 0, or not setting it at all is probably best option.